# Connect to Cloud SQL from node.js app on Compute Engine using knex

Tags: node.js, linux, postgresql, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

How do I connect to Cloud SQL from node.js app running in Compute engine using knex? I tried with public ip with and without cloud sql authproxy (tried to install and start proxy in a startup-script), but got error when calling endpoint with knex-connection:  KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?

Here's my startup script:

```
set -v

# Talk to the metadata server to get the project id
PROJECTID=$(curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")
REPOSITORY="..."
# CMS="..."

# Install logging monitor. The monitor will automatically pick up logs sent to
# syslog.
curl -s "https://storage.googleapis.com/signals-agents/logging/google-fluentd-install.sh" | bash
service google-fluentd restart &

# Install dependencies from apt
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential

apt-get install -yq ca-certificates git supervisor postgresql-client
apt-get install --yes liblcms2-2 liblcms2-dev liblcms2-utils

# Install nodejs
rm -r /opt/nodejs
mkdir /opt/nodejs
curl https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.0.0/node-v14.0.0-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar xvzf - -C /opt/nodejs --strip-components=1
ln -s -f /opt/nodejs/bin/node /usr/bin/node
ln -s -f /opt/nodejs/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
# Get the application source code from the Google Cloud Repository.
# git requires $HOME and it's not set during the startup script.
export HOME=/root
rm -r /opt/app
# rm -r /cms
git config --global credential.helper gcloud.sh
git clone https://source.developers.google.com/p/${PROJECTID}/r/${REPOSITORY} /opt/app


# Install app dependencies
cd /opt/app
git checkout development

npm install
npm install bunyan @google-cloud/logging-bunyan 
npm install sharp@0.29.0




# Create a nodeapp user. The application will run as this user.
cd /
cd /home/app
userdel -f app
cd /
rm -r /home/app
cd /opt/app
useradd -m -d /home/app app
chown -R app:app /opt/app
curl -o cloud-sql-proxy https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-sql-connectors/cloud-sql-proxy/v2.3.0/cloud-sql-proxy.linux.amd64
chmod +x cloud-sql-proxy
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/service-account-key/key.json
export INSTANCE_HOST='<public-ip>'
export DB_PORT='5432'
export DB_USER=’...’
export DB_PASS=’...’
export DB_NAME=’...’
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=dreamlouvre:europe-west1:dream-louvre-sql=tcp:5432 -credential_file=$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS &
# Configure supervisor to run the node app.
rm /etc/supervisor/conf.d/node-app.conf
cat >/etc/supervisor/conf.d/node-app.conf << EOF
[program:app]
directory=/opt/app
command=npm start
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=app
environment=HOME="/home/app",USER="app",NODE_ENV="development",SQL_CONNECTION_NAME="...",SQL_DB_NAME="...",SQL_USER="...",SQL_PW="...",
stdout_logfile=syslog
stderr_logfile=syslog
EOF
supervisorctl reread
supervisorctl update
# Application should now be running under supervisor
```

and here's my knex-instance script:

```
exports.initKnex = () => {

    const configuration = {
        user: config.config.sqlUser, // e.g. 'my-user'
        password: config.config.sqlPw, // e.g. 'my-user-password'
        database: config.config.sqlDbName, // e.g. 'my-database'
    };
    configuration.host = `${config.config.sqlConnectionName}`;
    const knex = Knex({client: 'pg', connection: configuration});
    knex.client.pool.max = 1;
    knex.client.pool.min = 1;
    knex.client.pool.createTimeoutMillis = 30000; // 30 seconds
    knex.client.pool.idleTimeoutMillis = 600000; // 10 minutes
    knex.client.pool.createRetryIntervalMillis = 200; // 0.2 seconds
    knex.client.pool.acquireTimeoutMillis = 600000; // 10 minutes
    return knex;
}
```

And here's the endpoint that causes the error:

```
exports.getCurrency = async (req, res) => {

    let response = {};
    try{
        response = await knex('exchangeRates').where({'countryCode': req.params.cc}).select('currencyCode', 'rate', 'digits');
        //console.log("RESPONSE: ", response);
      }
    catch (err){
        console.log("error: ", err);
        return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
    return res.status(200).json({'data':response});

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I noticed a couple things with your configuration.

Firstly, you are downloading v2 of the Cloud SQL Proxy (v2.3.0), yet your CLI invocation command is using v1 syntax `./cloud_sql_proxy`. This is the old v1 method, while `./cloud-sql-proxy` is used now in v2. You can view the [migration guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy/blob/main/migration-guide.md) for guidance on the differences between the two CLI commands and flags.

In short your `./cloud_sql_proxy` command in v2 form would be:

```
./cloud-sql-proxy --port=5432 --credentials-file=$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS dreamlouvre:europe-west1:dream-louvre-sql &
```

Secondly, since you are using the Cloud SQL Proxy, your `INSTANCE_HOST` variable should not be set to your Cloud SQL instance IP address, it should be set to `127.0.0.1` to interact with the Proxy.

Thirdly, it looks as though your Knex configuration is missing a `port` field being specified. It should look something like this ([see full code sample here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/main/cloud-sql/postgres/knex/connect-tcp.js))

```js
const configuration = {
  host: process.env.INSTANCE_HOST, // e.g. '127.0.0.1'
  port: process.env.DB_PORT, // e.g. '5432'
  user: process.env.DB_USER, // e.g. 'my-user'
  password: process.env.DB_PASS, // e.g. 'my-user-password'
  database: process.env.DB_NAME, // e.g. 'my-database'
}
```

Finally, my recommendation would be to use the [Cloud SQL Node.js Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector) instead of the Cloud SQL Proxy. It is a direct in-process replacement for the Proxy, that provides all the same benefits but in a native npm package.

You can install it as follows:

```
npm install @google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector
```

It also supports Knex like so:

```js
const Knex = require('knex');
const {Connector} = require('@google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector');

// connectWithConnector initializes connection pool for a Cloud SQL instance
// of Postgres using the Cloud SQL Node.js Connector.
const connectWithConnector = async config => {
  const connector = new Connector();
  const clientOpts = await connector.getOptions({
    instanceConnectionName: 'project-id:region:instance-name', // Cloud SQL Instance Connection Name
    ipType: 'PUBLIC',
  });
  const dbConfig = {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      ...clientOpts,
      user: process.env.DB_USER, // e.g. 'my-user'
      password: process.env.DB_PASS, // e.g. 'my-user-password'
      database: process.env.DB_NAME, // e.g. 'my-database'
    },
    // ... Specify additional properties here.
    ...config,
  };
  // Establish a connection to the database.
  return Knex(dbConfig);
```